# Initialize DataTable by SqlDataAdapter with System.Data.SqlTypes

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a code like:

```
using (var adapter = Db.Connection.Command(query).NewDataAdapter())
{
    adapter.Fill(initialDataSet);
}
```

where `NewDataAdapter()` returns new instance of `SqlDataAdapter`.
How I can force it to create `DataTable` in `DataSet` with columns using data types from `System.Data.SqlTypes` (e.g. `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid` instead of `System.Guid`)?

I have run following test:

```
static void Main()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    var column1 = table.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(SqlInt32));
    var column2 = table.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(Int32));

    Console.WriteLine($"Column1: {column1.DataType.FullName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Column2: {column2.DataType.FullName}");

    var row = table.NewRow();
    Console.WriteLine($"row[column1]: {row["Column1"]}, {row["Column1"].GetType().FullName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"row[column2]: {row["Column2"]}, {row["Column2"].GetType().FullName}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And got following result:

```
Column1: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32
Column2: System.Int32
row[column1]: Null, System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32
row[column2]: , System.DBNull
```

It shows that DataTable can store both CLR types and SqlTypes.

Comment: yes, but here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172137(v=vs.90).aspx is an example of DataTable with manually created SqlTypes columns. Though in current version of that article they have removed that example.

Comment: `typeof(SqlInt32)` creates column of `SqlInt32` - see code I have added in question body.

Comment: I have to retract my previous comments. I confused myself. I mixed up ` System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32` with enum `sqlDbType`. Yes, you can create a column because `SqlInt32` is a structure.

Comment: According to this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx, as long as your DB column type is `uniqueidentifier`, it should work

Comment: Yes, I can create data column manually with `SqlGuid` and it works perfectly. But if `DataTable` is created and populated by `DataAdapter.Fill()`, `Guid` is used for `uniqueidentifier` columns.

Comment: If you are interested why I want to use `SqlGuid`: `Guid` does not have dedicated data storage and is stored in `ObjectStorage`. When used in `DataTable.Select()` or in `DataView` filters etc, `Guid` values are converted to `String` and are searched and compared as strings. It causes issues in some Locales (due to local culture used in strings comparison), and is not very fast.

Comment: So, may be you need to use `system.guid` then?